# Authenticating the Ionic app with a backend server

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to create with angularjs based Ionic app an authentication mechanism. The system looks like this:

[image]

mobile users are created by administrators on the backend server. The created mobile user can login into the app.

I get an [Example](http://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/) and implemented it for my app.

**constants.js**

```
angular.module('starter')
    .constant('AUTH_EVENTS', {
      notAuthenticated: 'auth-not-authenticated',
      notAuthorized: 'auth-not-authorized'
    })
    .constant('USER_ROLES', {
      admin: 'admin_role',
      public: 'public_role'
    });
```

**dashController.js**

```
myApp.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $http, $ionicPopup, AuthService, $location, $window) {
    $scope.logout = function () {
        AuthService.logout();
        $window.location.href = '/index.html';
    };
    $scope.performValidRequest = function () {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8100/valid').then(
            function (result) {
                $scope.response = result;
            });
    };
    $scope.performUnauthorizedRequest = function () {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8100/notauthorized').then(
            function (result) {
                // No result here..
            }, function (err) {
                $scope.response = err;
            });
    };
    $scope.performInvalidRequest = function () {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8100/notauthenticated').then(
            function (result) {
                // No result here..
            }, function (err) {
                $scope.response = err;
            });
    };
});
```

**loginAppController.js**

```
myApp.controller('LoginAppCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS, $location, $window) {
    $scope.username = AuthService.username();

    $scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized, function (event) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Unauthorized!',
            template: 'You are not allowed to access this resource.'
        });
    });
    $scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated, function (event) {
        AuthService.logout();
        $window.location.href = '/loginPage.html';
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Session Lost!',
            template: 'Sorry, You have to login again.'
        });
    });
    $scope.setCurrentUsername = function (name) {
        $scope.username = name;
    };
})
```

**loginController.js**

```
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService, $location, $window) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.login = function (data) {
        AuthService.login(data.username, data.password).then(function (authenticated) {
            $window.location.href = '/index.html';
            $scope.setCurrentUsername(data.username);
        }, function (err) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login failed!',
                template: 'Please check your credentials!'
            });
        });
    };
})
```

**loginService.js**

```
angular.module('starter')

myApp.service('AuthService', function ($q, $http, USER_ROLES) {
    var LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY = 'yourTokenKey';
    var username = '';
    var isAuthenticated = false;
    var role = '';
    var authToken;

    function loadUserCredentials() {
        var token = window.localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
        if (token) {
            useCredentials(token);
        }
    }

    function storeUserCredentials(token) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY, token);
        useCredentials(token);
    }

    function useCredentials(token) {
        username = token.split('.')[0];
        isAuthenticated = true;
        authToken = token;

        if (username == 'admin') {
            role = USER_ROLES.admin
        }
        if (username == 'user') {
            role = USER_ROLES.public
        }

        // Set the token as header for your requests!
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = token;
    }

    function destroyUserCredentials() {
        authToken = undefined;
        username = '';
        isAuthenticated = false;
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = undefined;
        window.localStorage.removeItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
    }

    var login = function (name, pw) {
        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
            if ((name == 'admin' && pw == '1') || (name == 'user' && pw == '1')) {
                // Make a request and receive your auth token from your server
                storeUserCredentials(name + '.yourServerToken');
                resolve('Login success.');
            } else {
                reject('Login Failed.');
            }
        });
    };

    var logout = function () {
        destroyUserCredentials();
    };

    var isAuthorized = function (authorizedRoles) {
        if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
            authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
        }
        return (isAuthenticated && authorizedRoles.indexOf(role) !== -1);
    };

    loadUserCredentials();

    return {
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
        isAuthorized: isAuthorized,
        isAuthenticated: function () {
            return isAuthenticated;
        },
        username: function () {
            return username;
        },
        role: function () {
            return role;
        }
    };
})
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngMockE2E'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})

.run(function($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:8100/valid')
      .respond({message: 'This is my valid response!'});
    $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:8100/notauthenticated')
      .respond(401, {message: "Not Authenticated"});
    $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:8100/notauthorized')
      .respond(403, {message: "Not Authorized"});
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
})

  .run(function ($rootScope, $state, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS, $location, $window) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event,next, nextParams, fromState) {

      if ('data' in next && 'authorizedRoles' in next.data) {
        var authorizedRoles = next.data.authorizedRoles;
        if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
          $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized);
        }
      }

      if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
        if (next.name !== 'login') {
          event.preventDefault();
          $window.location.href = '/loginPage.html';
        }
      }
    });
  })
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-content style="text-align: left" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <span class="item item-input item-stacked-label"
          style="font-weight: bold">Name and password:</span>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Name:</span>
            <input name="name" placeholder="Name!" autofocus="true" required="true"
                   type="text"
                   ng-model="data.username"/>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Password:</span>
            <input name="password" placeholder="Password!" required="true" type="password"
                   ng-model="data.password"/>
        </label>
        <button id="button-1" class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="login(data)">Login</button>
 </ion-content>
```

In a related [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120693/creating-an-authentication-mechanism-with-angularjs-ionic-framework/33121183#33121183) I get these steps as an answer:

> 1) Send username password to server using $http.post();
>
> 2) Server authenticates the credentials. and returns a token in return
>   is credentials are correct.
>
> 3) App stores this token locally and passes it to server for later
>   request as a mean of identification of logged in user.
>
> Ideally you should implement SOAP or REST based services on your
>   server and consume those services in your app.

The example works localy. But where should change, so that I can authenticate with a user and password which stored on the backen server?

Comment: There is *a lot* of code here.  If you feel that your entire project is required in order to provide context, you should consider creating a working example on http://plnkr.co/ or similar, and only include highly relevant portions of the code in the question.  As it stands, many will stop reading before they reach the actual question at the very bottom.

Comment: @Claies Thanks for the note. I've created an [example](http://embed.plnkr.co/sLkf6K8lbXjYP0Cp9qIr/preview) on Plunker. But I get errors that I couldn't solve. The sample works well locally. But it doesn't work Only on Plunker. What could be the reason? thanks.